# The text label's text in my design wont change

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a text label inside of `Form1` named `txtOn`. I have made its modifier to `public`. Now I attempt to change the text using the following code with the click of a button. Nothing happens, but *button clicked!* is logged to debug.

How can I make the text of the text label change successfully?

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 home = new Form1();
        home.txtOn.Text = "test!";

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("button clicked!");
    }
```

Comment: Why you initialize Form instance `Form1 home = new Form1();`? You should use already defined variable `txtOn`.

Comment: Why are you instanitating a new instance of  `Form1` in your button click?  Simply do `this.txtOn.Text = "test1";`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you haven't loaded the new instance of form1.

```
Form1 home = new Form1();
home.show();
home.txton.text="test!";
```

If you want to change it on the current instance of the form you will need to use the this keyword:

```
this.txton.text="test!";
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want either

```
// Start NEW Form1, show it and change the button
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 home = new Form1();

    home.txtOn.Text = "test!";
    home.Show(); // <- do not forget to show the form

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("button clicked!");
}
```

or

```
// On the EXISTING Form1 instance change the button
// providing that "button1_Click" method belongs to "Form1" class
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtOn.Text = "test!";

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("button clicked!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is not working because you are re instantiating Form1 when it's already available.  You are changing the text of a button not on the same instance as the one on the ui

Try

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 

        txtOn.Text = "test!";

}
```

.

Answer (score 0):

NO, change that labels text in your Form load or initialize method like

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 home = new Form1();
        home.Show();     
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("button clicked!");
    }

Public Form1()
{
  txtOn.Text = "test!";
}
```

Assuming you are trying to open a different form altogether. If it's the same form then you don't need to create a separate form instance at all. You can just say `txtOn.Text = "test!";`

Answer (score 0):

You must create Form1 only once.
Sample

```
`Form1 home = new Form1();
home.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        home.txtOn.Text = "test!";

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("button clicked!");
    }`
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to expose your label or its property.

In form 2

```
public string LabelText
    {
        get
        {
            return this.txtOn.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            this.txtOn.Text = value;
        }
    }
```

Then you can do:

```
form2 frm2 = new form2();
frm2.LabelText = "test";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating one more object of the same form again. So the label not getting changed. Try the code bellow.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtOn.Text = "test!";

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("button clicked!");
    }
```